# Why does logcat ignore log statements with tag "PHONE"?

Tags: android, tags, logcat

I was setting a listener on my call button and at first I just wanted to make sure that the listener was working, so I put a log statement inside of it. But for some mysterious reason, it refused to print when I clicked it! So maybe the call button was null, I thought, and added an else statement...but it didn't print anything from either the if or the else statement!!! It would print the statements before and after, but totally ignore everything in the if-else structure. Here's the code:

```
ImageButton call = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.callButton);

Log.d("MEETINGS", "ABOUT TO WORK W/ CALL");
Log.e("MEETINGS", "" + (call != null));

if (call != null) {
    Log.d("PHONE", "setting stuff on call...");
    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("PHONE", "on call : " + phone);
        }
    });
} else {
System.out.println("why is this messed up");
Log.d("PHONE", "call button was null!");
}

System.out.println("what the heck is going on");
```

After at least 15 minutes of trying to unravel the mystery of how Java could just decide to skip both the if and the else, I tried giving the log statement a different tag.

And eureka! That did the trick! I changed "PHONE" to "BLAH" and suddenly the world made sense again! Curious, I changed it to "phone" and it refuses to print again.

Moral of the story: never use the tag "phone" or "PHONE" in logcat!!!

Can someone please explain to me how and/or why logcat ignores messages with the tag "PHONE"?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [isLoggable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). I'm guessing debug output for the "PHONE" tag has been disabled on your phone to suppress output from the actual phone application.

I believe you should be able to run "getprop log.tag.PHONE" in a shell on the phone to retrieve the minimum severity level required for messages tagged "PHONE" to be printed.